# pandas groupby multiple columns gives weird index behavior

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have data as below, with 7 columns. I want to merge all rows that have the same value in columns 1-6, and sum the corresponding column-7 data.

```
0.1  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.001
0.1  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.002
0.9  0.9  0.9  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.002
0.9  0.9  0.9  0.8  0.8  0.8  0.1 
0.9  0.9  0.9  0.8  0.8  0.8  0.2 
0.1  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.001
0.1  0.2  0.3  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.002
0.9  0.9  0.9  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.002
```

I had tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test-data',sep='\s+',header=None,engine='python')
key1_sum = df1.groupby([0,1,2,3,4,5]).sum()

print(key1_sum)
```

I expected to get this output:

```
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.1  0.002
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.2 0.3  0.004
0.9 0.9 0.9 0.1 0.1 0.1  0.004
0.9 0.9 0.9 0.8 0.8 0.8  0.300
```

...but I actually got this output:

```
                             6
0   1   2   3   4   5         
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.1  0.002
                0.2 0.3  0.004
0.9 0.9 0.9 0.1 0.1 0.1  0.004
            0.8 0.8 0.8  0.300
```

So I just want to not output the head, 
and complete the elements in the corresponding column.

Could you please give me some suggestions about that?

Comment: [pandas groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by default has `as_index=True, group_keys=True`. So if you grouped by multiple columns, that default will gives you an unwanted MultiIndex. Set `as_index=False`  to  get “SQL-style” grouped output (no funky row index).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we try to `groupby` is we do not want the `groupby` key as `index`, we can pass to the `as_index=False`

```
key1_sum = df1.groupby([0,1,2,3,4,5],as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: Another way to get the same result is to do `key1_sum = df1.groupby([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).sum().reset_index()`.

Answer (score 0):

[pandas groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by default has `as_index=True, group_keys=True`:

- **so if you grouped by multiple columns, the default will give you an (often unwanted) MultiIndex**
- set `as_index=False` to get “SQL-style” grouped output (no funky row index)